# JavaFX How to display 2 empty rows in TableView on pageLoad?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a TableView in AchorPane. On page load the table should display 2 empty rows. To achieve this i have coded like this:

```
final ObservableList<ContainerVO> tblReceiptContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tblReceiptContent.add(new ContainerVO());
tblReceiptContent.add(new ContainerVO());
tblReceipt.setItems(tblReceiptContent);
```

I think its not the proper way. I dont wat to create a List with 2 items. The List should be empty. Item should be added when i edit the empty row in table.Is there any better way to display empty rows?

Comment: As TableView works with databinding, I don't see another way. It is quite logical to have two lines. If you "hack" something to not have a collection with items, you'll probably break the databinding.

Answer (score 0):

when you make observation list does not initalized its property...

try this...

```
final ObservableList tblReceiptContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
tblReceiptContent.add("");
tblReceiptContent.add("");
tblReceiptContent.add(new ContainerVO());
```